# How to Perform Fastest Redirection?

Tags: php, html, web

I am planning to redirect a url, which type of redirect is fastest? Meta or some other?

I want to keep a track on how many people are redirect and their demographics. So will be implementing Google Analytics with it.

How can i implement GA in redirect? Can i use GA code with redirects?

Comment: Any problem with the redirect speed you are experiencing right now?

Comment: No, problem. But some trouble with some tracking and user experiences.

Comment: Any one care to explain down, vote? Not even single good answer.

Comment: Please have a look at diversity of my question and provide some valuable code.

Comment: @LaimeNekurzeme I disagree that there are no good answers.  The Apache redirect answer will give you the fastest redirect since it won't pass the request along to PHP (less overhead, faster response).  If that's not good enough because you need to perform some logic then a header redirect will be the next quickest.  Finally, if you really need to use it, you could use a meta redirect.  If you're not getting the answer you're looking for then ask better questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the server, you could redirect on an Apache server with the .htaccess

I think that is faster compared to the meta/header technique, but that needs some testing to prove.

Comment: in case there is no logic involved (like some DB result)

Answer (score 1):

```
header('Location: http://...');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think 
`<?php header("Location: http://yourlocation"); ?>` would help you redirect fast

Answer (score -1):

Using a header would be the fastest. Make you should put this before sending any content. Meta redirects are relatively slow because they require the client to do the HTML parsing.

```
header("Location: NewPage.php");
```

Comment: OMG, "do the HTML parsing". As though to parse 2 lines of HTML is more job than parsing 10 lines of headers.